# Determine if my app is in the top row on tvOS

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I am prioritizing features for my tvOS app and am interested in gauging the impact of a potential [tvOS Top Shelf integration](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/overview/top-shelf/).

Before I spend time developing the feature, I want to know what % of my users have my app in the top row on their Apple TV, and would therefore be able to see the Top Shelf recommendations.

Is there any way suss this out? I wonder if there is some method that gets called if my app is in the top row, where I could add some logging.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you have your own custom TopShelfContent as mentioned here -> https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/icons-and-images/top-shelf-content/

Your custom Views will be called, so you can get a logic of your app is on the top Shelf. Otherwise, these customView won't be called.